# Correct way to loop pages from web to .csv? & Not all data entered in some columns

Tags: python, web-scraping, html-table

I am almost where I need to be with this project, but my current problem is that the loop I have set up, simply repeats the 25 players listed on page 1...any ideas on how to get this to actually loop through the different pages of the table?
Secondly, on the league-left and club-joined sections, random data is missing and I can't seem to fix that... below I have added my code and what my .csv looks like with the gaps in data.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv


def get_page(url):
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36'}
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    return soup


def get_table(soup):
    rows = []
    player_table = soup.find_all('table', class_='items')
    player_table = player_table[0]
    for row in player_table.select('tbody > tr'):
        num = row.select('td')[0].get_text()
        name = row.select('td')[3].get_text().replace('\n', '')
        position = row.select('td')[4].get_text()
        age = row.select('td')[5].get_text()
        market_value = row.select('td')[6].get_text()
        nationality = row.contents[5].contents[0].attrs['title']
        left_club = row.select('td > a')[2].get_text()
        left_league = row.select('td > a')[3].get_text()
        joined_club = row.select('td > a')[-2].get_text()
        joined_league = row.select('td > a')[-1].get_text()
        fee = row.select('td')[-1].get_text()
        row = [num, name, position, age, market_value, nationality, left_club, left_league, joined_club, joined_league, fee]
        rows.append(row)
    return rows


def write_csv(rows, i):
    with open('players4.csv', 'a', newline='') as r:
        file = csv.writer(r)
        if i == 1:
            columns = ['Number', 'Name', 'Position', 'Age', 'Market Value', 'Nationality', 'Club Left', 'League Left',
                       'Club Joined', 'League Joined', 'Transfer Fee']
            file.writerow(columns)
            for row in rows:
                file.writerow(row)
        else:
            for row in rows:
                file.writerow(row)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    for i in range(1, 3):
        print('Page', i)
        url = f'https://www.transfermarkt.com/transfers/saisontransfers/statistik/top/plus/1/galerie/0?saison-id=2020&transferfenster=alle&land_id=&ausrichtung=&spielerposition_id=&altersklasse=&leihe='
        soup = get_page(url)
        rows = get_table(soup)
        write_csv(rows, i)
```

[image: .csv image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to build the url dynamically with the page number

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    page = 1
    while True:
        # build page url dynamically by adding page=? query string
        url = 'https://www.transfermarkt.com/transfers/saisontransfers/statistik?land_id=&ausrichtung=&spielerposition_id=&altersklasse=&leihe=&transferfenster=alle&saison-id=2020&plus=1&page={0}'.format(page)        
        soup = get_page(url)
        rows = get_table(soup)
        total = len(rows)
        print('Page: ', page, ' total rows: ', total)

        write_csv(rows, page)

        if total < 25: # if we got less than 25 rows break 
            break
        page += 1 # increment page
```